# Setting up a logs-only subversion mirror

Tags: svn, version-control, mirror

Not sure whether this should be asked here or on another site such as superuser.com, but I'm going with here for now since this is still programming-related.

We're currently using an internal svn server for version control, and an offsite hosted system for issue tracking and planning.  The issue tracker has support for svn integration, but it works by requiring the svn repository be internet accessible and giving it login credentials, which I'm not comfortable with since it potentially exposes proprietary source code.

So what I'd like to do instead is to set up a read-only "mirror repository", which contains all the same revisions and commit logs, and possibly even the same directory structure (so you can see which files were changed in each commit), but absolutely none of the actual file contents.  But I'm not sure where to start looking.  Most of the svn mirrors I can find (understandably) focus on providing a "normal" mirror.  Any suggestions?

(Another possibility is to write a commit hook that pushes the desired changes to the issue tracker, but that seems like more work as it would have to duplicate the functionality of the integrated pull system that already exists.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an interesting-looking answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/152289/restrict-subversion-to-only-allow-certain-functions).

And yes, it seems to work; adding this to the http.conf makes it behave as I want:

```
<Location /svn/>
     <LimitExcept OPTIONS PROPFIND REPORT>
         deny from all
     </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

(I had a bit of trouble at first until I worked out which module I had to load to get support for "deny".)